# apache alias not working

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I defined the following alias

```
Alias /static/images /images
```

However when I browse to `localhost/myweb/static/images` I am getting:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /myweb/static/images was not found on this server.

Why isn't it redirecting to `localhost/myweb/images`?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias mind the warning at the end of this section about Directory.

Answer (score 0):

`Alias` is not for redirecting but for mapping URLs to file system pathes, usually outside your `DocumentRoot`.

```
Alias /static/images /images
```

tells Apache that if you request `localhost/static/images` it should look at the folder `/images` in your filesystem. Quite likely this folder doesn't exist and you get an error.

See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) for more about the `Alias` directive.

---

If you want to redirect `localhost/myweb/static/images` to `localhost/myweb/images` you need to use the `Redirect` directive instead, for example

```
Redirect  seeother /myweb/static/images /myweb/images
```

See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) for more about the `Redirect` directive.

Comment: the `images` folder does exist, that's the whole point of what I'm trying to do

Comment: That is not how Alias works. Try it yourself. Apache will NOT serve images in your local filesystem's `/images/*` to `http://localhost/static/images/*`.